# Rails 5 Active Storage Paperclip-style Thumbnail Form Preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, rails-activestorage

With Paperclip, in a Rails 3 form, you could generate a thumbnail preview of an uploaded photo like so:

```
form do |f|
f.input :photo, :required => false, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.photo.url(:thumb))
end
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to do the same thing with Active Storage in Rails 5.  So far I've tried:

```
f.input :photo, required: false, as: :file, hint: image_tag(f.photo.preview(resize: "200x200"))
```

But I get an error that:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `photo'
```

Comment: What is `:cavatar`?

Comment: Ah... "photo". Same thing. (Meant to change that.)